# Command line argument variable @ARGV

Tags: perl, arguments, argv

I have a task to convert script from Perl to PowerShell.

I read about command line argument of Perl: `@ARGV`. I understand that at the time of the script execution, any argument that is passed will be captured by this special array variable. We can read `@ARGV` and assign values to scalar variables using:

```
($var1,$var2) = @ARGV;
```

I need to understand what the statement below is doing:

```
($var1,$var2,@ARGV) = @ARGV;
```

In my script, I have an `if` condition on values in `@ARGV`, and based on `@ARGV` values, a respective subroutine is getting called.

As per my understanding if we have more than two values in `@ARGV`, then on left side in parenthesis statement is changing values of ARGV/used to rewrite `@ARGV` with remaining Values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It chops off the first two arguments from @ARGV and puts them in $var1 and $var2.

Personally I would have written it as:

```
$var1 = shift @ARGV;
$var2 = shift @ARGV;
```

But it is a matter of taste.

Comment: I probably wouldn't have done even that `my ( $first, $second, @everything_else ) = @ARGV;` is more my sort of thing :)

Comment: @Sobrique There may be a call to [GetOptions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) later in the script, which would require the modification of `@ARGV`.